# File Permissions issue from same group

Tags: permissions, chmod

I have a folder that I haven't created and belongs to a `web-group` group. Even though my username is under that group I can't modify files or create new ones without doing `sudo`.

When I do the following code to my folder: `chmod g+rwxs`

I can solve the problem then.

So my question is:

Why is this happening and what `g+rwxs` means?

I know that `r` is read `w` is write and `x` is execute, `g` is for group. However I get confuse to decode the full permission rule.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why is this happening: Probably because the permissions (prior to you changing them with "chmod g+rwxs") didn't allow for the group to modify the file. eg. your group only had read permissions, and the (o)ther group didn't have write permissions either...

What does "g+rwxs" mean:  For the (g)roup add (+) (r)ead, (w)rite, e(x)ecute, (s)UID permissions (as the group) to the file/folder.

FYI - The sticky/SUID bit most likely is not required in your situation and chmod "g+rwx" would suffice.